# Calculate the aggregated standard deviation of several samples

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, survey

I have the following survey-based data, where the first row is the aggregate of the other rows (Emp1-Emp5).

```
        Mean    Median  Lowest  Highest SD      SE     Responses No responses   
Agg_Emp 2.750   2.700   0.800   4.500   0.648   0.041   254         16  94%
Emp1    2.711   2.800   0.800   4.000   0.696   0.134   27          1   96%
Emp2    2.962   3.000   1.500   4.500   0.642   0.140   21          3   88%
Emp3    2.794   2.530   1.500   4.500   0.686   0.079   75          3   96%
Emp4    2.863   3.000   1.500   4.300   0.653   0.076   73          6   92%
Emp5    2.491   2.500   1.400   3.500   0.495   0.065   58          3   95%
```

What I want to do is to calculate the standard deviation of Emp1 and Emp2. Before doing that though, I want to use the Emp1-Emp5 to replicate the standard deviation of Agg_emp, to assure myself that I'm doing it correctly.

My idea was to calculate the variance for each observation as SE^2 multiplied by the number of responses (n). I then weighted each variance by n/254, added them up, and took the standard deviation as the square of the variance.

Unfortunately my standard deviation came out somewhat differently from the standard deviation reported for the variable Agg_emp. What am I doing wrong? Should I perhaps correct somehow for the response rate?

Comment: Your second paragraph has issues. First of all, the standard deviation is the *square root* of the variance. Also, it is imperative that you have the original data in order to do what you want to do.

Comment: Somethign I just thought of - what are the responses? Are these continuous variables or something like a 0-5 scale? If it's the latter, then mean and standard deviation are meaningless.